# How to move Images and Containers to new Server with historical data

Tags: docker

image :

```
docker save -o /root/bkp1/docker_image_bkp ccn/ccn-server:1.0.4
```

Container:

```
docker export cef0dff04e70 > /root/bkp1/container.tar
```

In new server :

```
docker load -i /root/pmmbkp1/docker_image_bkp

cat /root/bkp1/container.tar | docker import - ccdata
```

And I created and started it. But I am not able find the old data in the new server. How do I move the historical data along with the containers?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Sep 2016), NONE of `docker save` or `docker export` or even `docker commit` could produce a tar file that includes any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

In a short, if you want move volume data from one server to another, the best way is using shared file system to store your docker container's data. Please check the [Mount a shared-storage volume as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume) document.

Once you have a shared storage for your Docker cluster, you could stop your old container in the original server, then use the same configurations to start a new container in another server. Both of the old container and the new container should mount the same volume that existing in the shared storage system.

Data Persistent is still a problem in Docker's orchestration system. But another orchestration tool, Kubernetes 1.4, now support [Persistent Volumes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/walkthrough/).

EDIT:

If your container is already running and you want to move it around, you may try to do the following steps:

1. Save your original container to a image with `docker save` or `docker commit`. Then load the saved image to the new server.
2. Check the mount points of original container, then find the local volume files with your mount points configuration. For example, with `docker inspect`, you can find something similar to this:

   "Mounts": [

   ```
   {
       "Name": "95d7a2419c62242149562d5098edcc7578754ae2f3c35a45c4d690f3c340905a",
       "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/95d7a2419c62242149562d5098edcc7578754ae2f3c35a45c4d690f3c340905a/_data",
       "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
       "Driver": "local",
       "Mode": "",
       "RW": true,
       "Propagation": ""
   }
   ```

   ],

Here you can see the mount point is `"/var/lib/docker/volumes/95d7a2419c62242149562d5098edcc7578754ae2f3c35a45c4d690f3c340905a/_data"`

3. Copy your local volume file to the new server.
4. Start a new container in the new server, where new container should mount the copy of original local volume file to it. You can use `docker run` command's `-v` parameter to achieve it.
5. You may need consider to use the same configuration to start new container in the new server. `docker inspect` command can help you find out the configuration of a container, as well as the mount point configuration.

Above solution might looks complicated and ugly, but there is no other way to move container easily unless you are using shared-storage.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details on the shared storage. But in my case the docker's image, container and the data is in the local disk on the server. How do I move the data to new server ?

Comment: @user1638016 Hi, sorry for the later reply, I updated my answer please check it out.

Comment: Hi Haoming, Can you please share the command I have to use for chaining the mount source for the data container. I have copied the data container to the new server (/var/lib/docker/volumes/7362bc5fa96cbc2cca9572b6c4890e54be519c1ad516af5f804c28ec7e7fab69/_data) bust not sure how to get it mounted with the container. (docker create  -v /opt/nms/data  --name nms-data nms/nms-server:2.0.8 /bin/true)

Comment: (docker create  -v /opt/nms/data  --name nms-data nms/nms-server:2.0.8 /bin/true )   docker inspect shows different source on the new server  "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/0f34b5ae21d3794ef62bcb8ad42b8f12559450f969aca90174a5d07f7c6d9749/_data", )

Comment: Check this https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ . `-v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp` where `/src/webapp` is your local directory, and `/opt/webapp` is the directory in your container. Any file in `/src/webapp` will be accessible in your container's `/opt/webapp` folder